# Stuck on this MBR2GPT (Cannot find OS Partition) issue

Tags: uefi, windows-11, mbr, gpt

I'm trying to use MBR2GPT to convert an MBR/BIOS disk to GPT/UEFI. I'm getting the error Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 4. I found this in setupact.log:

```
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         MBR2GPT was explicitly asked to run in full OS mode.
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         MBR2GPT: Attempting to validate disk 4
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         MBR2GPT: Retrieving layout of disk
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         MBR2GPT: Initial partition information
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         ===========================================================
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         Partition layout for disk: 4
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         Partition style          : MBR
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         MBR signature: 2079525136
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         Number of partitions     : 2
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Number: 1
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                                Type: 7
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                                Boot: Yes
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                               Style: 0
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Offset: 1048576
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Length: 268435456000
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{7bf30910-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                               Drive: C:\
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk4\Partition1
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Number: 2
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                                Type: 7
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                                Boot: No
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                               Style: 0
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Offset: 268436504576
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Length: 209715200
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{7bf30910-0000-0000-0000-10803e000000}\
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                               Drive: X:\
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk4\Partition2
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         ===========================================================
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         ESP partition size will be 104857600
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         BCD: Opening store. Flags: 0x0
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         BCD: Store path: "\??\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1\Boot\BCD"
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         BCD: Failed to load hive into key BCD00000000 from \??\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1\Boot\BCD. Status: c000000f
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Info                         BCD: BcdOpenStore: Failed to add store from file \??\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1\Boot\BCD. StoreFlags: 0x0 Status: c000000f
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Error                        FindOSPartitions: Cannot open BCD for boot volume. Error: 0xC000000F
2022-12-07 15:38:24, Error                        Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 4
```

Command I'm running:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mbr2gpt /validate /allowFullOS /disk:4
MBR2GPT: Attempting to validate disk 4
MBR2GPT: Retrieving layout of disk
MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 4
```

bcdedit (as admin):

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=G:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {069b9e52-330a-11ed-9d60-fc82c62dfcb6}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {069b9e54-330a-11ed-9d60-fc82c62dfcb6}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {069b9e52-330a-11ed-9d60-fc82c62dfcb6}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

[Disk Management screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5CFZ.png)

Comment: https://www.diskpart.com/gpt-mbr/mbr2gpt-cannot-find-os-partition-7201.html

Comment: Your partition layout is incompatible with MBR2GPT, you won’t be able to use that particular tool, best to just reinstall Windows properly allowing it to create the necessary additional partitions.

Answer (score 2):

For people who have same issue, my solution was using the command `bcdboot C:\Windows /s Y: /f ALL`

Where **C:** is your OS location and **Y:** is the assigned volume letter for your boot partition. Normally is the System Reserve partition in Bios/Legacy schema. I recommend creating a backup first in case something goes wrong.

I experienced exact error message "Cannot open BCD for boot volume" when using mbr2gpt and that command above solved my issue.

This command copies BCD files that support booting on either UEFI-based or BIOS-based computer.

If you can't assign a letter to the System Reserve partition from the Disk Management you can from Diskpart.
On elevated command prompt run `Diskpart`

On example if System Reserve is my partition 2 from Disk 1, I would do:

```
DISKPART > sel disk 1
DISKPART > sel part 2
DISKPART > assign letter=Y
```

Exit and try running mbr2gpt again.